# "Oh My gosh & "Oh my God"?

Tags: meaning

> oh my gosh.

I've heard some people say "**oh my gosh**" instead of "Oh my God."

Do these two mean the same thing?
I searched the web and found an explanation, but I don't know if it is an valid answer or no:

The explanation is:

"*The difference is that some people see oh my gosh as far more polite than oh my god. The reason for this is that many religious people believe that you shouldn’t use god’s name in vain which means you shouldn’t associate god’s name with something bad.*" [1](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/question/oh-my-gosh-vs-oh-my-god/)

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gosh

Comment: closely related: [What can I say politely when something bad happens?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-can-i-say-politely-when-something-bad-happens) and [Is it an idiom or slang: holy mac and cheese?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52031/is-it-an-idiom-or-slang-holy-mac-and-cheese) and [What is another word for “sh*t”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23570/what-is-another-word-for-sht)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the two phrases is correct and that is the usual explanation for using one over the other.

Comment: I've heard the expression "minced oath" tossed around... This is a good comment, but hardly a substantive answer.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath